# Mutually exclusive releases in microsoft release management

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to be able to see the results of each GUItest-project seperately in CatLight.

My idea on how to solve this is to have them as seperate releases for each GUI-testproject. This would make it possible to have them separetely in CatLight.

My problem is that i can't have the release start during the GUI-tests. So i would like to mark the GUI-test with a semaphore of sorts and mark the release with the same, so they can't run together. I can't find any logical way of doing this in Microsoft release management, but it sounds like a common restriction.

So this would be the setup,

Release definitins:

Deploy to testMachine

GUI-tests for product A

GUI-tests for product B

GUI-tests for product C

The deploy is only allowed to run when no GUI-tests run. The GUI-Tests are allowed to run parallel. So i'm thinking about having three metaphores: A, B, C. The Deploy takes all of those and the GUI-tests one each.

Is there any way to do this, or plugin for this or another solution that is not visible for me?

Today we do the GUI tests as tasks in the deployment, the problem with this is that the different teams have to check to see if it's their gui-tests that have trouble if one fails...

Comment: Do you mean this release: [Release definitions in Release Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/), I don't understand clearly of your scenario, can you provide the sample to explain it?

Comment: Added some more examples and yes, its the Release Management in the link.

Comment: Do you mean there are four release definitions? What's the workflow you want? What's the expect result?

Comment: When the "Deploy to testMachine" have finished i want "GUI-tests for product A", "GUI-tests for product B" and "GUI-tests for product C" to start. I want them reported seperately in catlight so Team A don't have to see fails in B and C... a new deploy isn't allowed while any of the GUI-tests still runs.

So yes, for the moment 4 different release definitions.

Comment: How about a release definition with four environments? After that when "deploy to testMachine" environment has finished, the GUI-test for Product A, GUI-test for Product B and GUI-test for Product C environments will be started.